# Questions about Lebesgue integral of increasing measurable function converges in measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm doing an exercise in Lebesgue integral.

Definitions probably used:

> Some of them can be acquired here: [Questions of an exercise in Lebesgue integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387418/questions-of-an-exercise-in-lebesgue-integral).
>
> Definition of **Convergence in measure**: Suppose $f(x), f_1(x), f_2(x),..., f_k(x), ...$ are Lebesgue measurable functions that are finite almost everywhere ($m(\{x \in E: |f_k(x)| = +\infty\}) = 0$). $\{f_k(x)\}$ **converge in measure** to $f(x)$ if for $\forall \epsilon > 0,$ $\lim_{k \to \infty} m(\{ x\in E: |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon\}) = 0$.

**Exercise3:**

Plese note it is based on Lebesgue integral.

Suppose $0 \le f_1(x) \le f_2(x) \le ... \le f_k(x) \le ...(x \in E)$ and $f_k(x)$ converges in measurable to $f(x)$, then show $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{E} f_k(x) dx = \int_{E} f(x) dx.$$

**My trial and trouble:**

There is no solution for this exercise.
I tried to use **Riesz's theorem of convergence in measure** that is,

suppose $\{f_k(x)\}$ converge in measure to $f(x)$, then there exist a subsequence of $\{f_k(x)\}$, named $\{f_{k_i}(x)\}$ such that $\lim f_{k_i}(x) = f(x),$ almost everywhere, $ x \in E.$

I can prove $\lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{E} f_{k_i}(x) dx = \int_{E} f(x) dx.$ However, I don't know how to show $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{E} f_k(x) dx = \lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{E} f_{k_i}(x) dx.$ The trouble is I can take $\lim$ into $\int_{E} f_{k_i}(x)$ by monotone convergence theorem that is $$\lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{E} f_{k_i}(x) dx = \int_{E} \lim_{i \to \infty} f_{k_i}(x) dx.$$ But I can't do that for $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{E} f_k(x) dx$ coz $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x)$ may not exist.

Comment: a monotone sequence of reals numbers has a accumulation point at most

Comment: @user251257: What did you mean by "accumulation"? What is accumulation point? I know definition of limit point.

Comment: For almost every $x\in E$, you have $f_{k_{i}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$. $(f_{k}(x))$ is a monotone increasing sequence of real numbers, and $(f_{k_{i}}(x))$ converges to $f(x)$, and thus is bounded above by $f(x)$. It follows that $f(x)$ is also an upper bound for $(f_{k}(x))$, and so $(f_{k}(x))\rightarrow f(x)$.

Comment: @catfish: Show it is a least upper bounded as well coz for any value smaller a little bit than it, there will exist $\int_{E} f_{k_j}(x)dx$ greater than this value for some $j$, right?

Comment: Yup, since $(f_{k_{i}}(x))\rightarrow f(x)$, $f(x)$ is a least upper bound for $(f_{{k}_{i}}(x))$, so it will have to be a least upper bound for $(f_{k}(x))$.

Comment: @catfish: Amazed by your comment! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bearandbunny yes. for sequence they are the same concept

Comment: @catfish: Can you share with me how did you come with idea of monotone sequence bounded above?

Comment: In general, any convergent sequence in a metric space is bounded, so if $(f_{k_{i}}(x))$ consists of real numbers and converges, it is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$. It might be a little trickier here if we're working with the extended real line, $[-\infty,\infty]$ which is not a metric space on its own (it is homeomorphic to one however), but we're given that each $f_{k}$ is finite almost everywhere, and countable unions of measure 0 sets still have measure 0, so I think we should still be able to conclude via the monotone convergence theorem. Have you been able to solve it yet?

Comment: @catfish: Yes, proof will be easy to handle with your comment. I've noticed you mention that extended real line is homeomorphic to one. I'm not sure what did you mean by "homeomorphic to one". Homeomorphic to [0,1]? Besides, I checked my real analysis book(Carothers' real analysis) that homeomorphism is a property between two metric space, so is it appropriate to use "homeomorphic" here?

Comment: I mean as topological spaces; both $[-\infty,\infty]$ and $[0,1]$ are topological spaces under the order topology, and $[-\infty,\infty]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. $[-\infty,\infty]$ is not a metric space but $[0,1]$ is (and the standard metric on $[0,1]$ induces the same topology as the order on $[0,1]$ does). This would allow us to consider the image of a sequence in $[-\infty,\infty]$ by the homemorphism which would then be a sequence in $[0,1]$ with the same topological properties.

Comment: @catfish: Got you. Make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\in E$ we have $\lim_{i\to\infty } f_{k_i} (x) =\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k (x)$ since $(f_n)$ is monotone.
Analogously for the monotone sequence $a_k =\int_E f_k (t) dt $ we get $\lim_{i\to\infty} a_{k_i} =\lim_{k\to \infty } a_k .$